# How do I use predefined directives (ng-click) with custom directives in a nested fashion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

How do I ng-click to work for the button in ngSearchBar.html? I want to use the same scope as my parent directive (ngSearchBar.html) for my child directive (ng-click), so that I can do scope.search = function() {}; in my parent directive.

```
myAppControllers.constant('baseDomainConstant', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/');

myAppControllers.factory('technologiesFactory', ['$resource', 'baseDomainConstant', function($resource, baseDomainConstant) {
    return $resource(baseDomainConstant + 'technologies.json', {}, null);
}]);

myAppControllers.directive('ngSearchBar', ['technologiesFactory', function(technologiesFactory) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: "partials/ngSearchBar.html",
    replace: true,
    scope: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        var data = '';

        scope.search = function() {
            console.log('TESTING');
        };

        element.find('#search').on('click', function() {
            alert(JSON.stringify($('.select2').select2('data')));
        });

        technologiesFactory.get().$promise.then(function(result) {
            _.forEach(result.data, function(technologyNames, category) {
                data += '<optgroup label="' + category + '">';
                _.forEach(technologyNames, function(technology) {
                    data += '<option value="' + technology.technology_id + '">' + technology.webname + '</option>';
                });
                data += '</optgroup>';
            });

            element.find('#multi-append').append(data);
            $('.select2').select2('enable', true);

        });
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $('.select2').select2({ placeholder: 'Search' });
        $('.select2').select2('enable', false);

        $scope.search = function() {
            console.log('TESTING');
        };

    }]
};
}]);

myAppControllers.controller('ViewCtrlv2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.search = function() { console.log('Testing'); };
    }]
);
```

This is partials/ngSearchBar.html"

```
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
    <div class="input-append">
        <select id="multi-append" class="select2" multiple="multiple" style="width:400px;"></select>
        <button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="search()">
            <i class="icon-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where I'm using my directive. The HTML.

```
<div class="wrapper dashboard inc-footer">

<div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>

<span data-ng-search-bar></span>

<div class="sticky-footer" ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me the html where you using the directive.

Comment: There it is. It's at the bottom code box. The header/footer are static html partials. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Can you see that the directive gets run? Or any errors in the console window?

Comment: It gets run. No problems are showing up. The directive work. But the nested ng-click doesn't. It's a scope issue.

Comment: Just to check something. Put a function on the directive controller scope and see if that executes.

Comment: Just did for both the link and the controller functions. $scope.search and scope.search. Nothing. The changes are at the top.

Comment: Ok I thought that might happen. Now try removing the data-select2-open attribute. Maybe it's blocking the click event.

Comment: Nope. I removed the attribute as shown above. I also added a $scope.search = function() { console.log('TESTING'); } to my main view controller for angular-routes. Still nothing.

Comment: You have an unclosed div tag in the template. .control-group. But I doubt that's it.

Comment: What happens if you replace ng-click with the following. onclick="angular.element(this).scope().search()"

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click` inside a template should work just fine. If you want the directive to share the parent scope however you should put `scope: false` on the directive definition object.

P.s. Also I don't know if your interested but there is a select2 wrapper directive written if you want to abstract away the jquery plugin. [angular ui select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2)

Comment: If you already tried it like this and it doesn't work then let me know.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the reply. However, this doesn't work. I added `scope: false` property to my ngSearchBar directive and still nothing. Can you give me a snippet so I can test it?